# Item count using arbitrary time periods in PySpark

Tags: date, group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following format

```
row |    date    | user
------------------------
 1  | 2017/09/10 | user1 
 2  | 2017/09/28 | user1 
 3  | 2017/09/30 | user1 
 4  | 2017/10/01 | user1 
 5  | 2017/10/08 | user2 
 6  | 2017/11/01 | user2
 7  | 2017/10/15 | user3
 8  | 2017/10/22 | user3
```

I need to generate a count of unique users within consecutive 6-week periods (i.e. unique users count within the first 6 weeks of 2017, then unique user count within the second 6-week period, and so on.)

Can someone please suggest a way to achieve this in PySpark/SQL?

Spark 2.3.0 and Python 3

Answer (score 2):

Found a way around this problem by modifying code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129733/group-by-a-pyspark-dataframe-by-time-interval). As an example:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(
[
    ("A", "2017/09/01"), 
    ("B", "2017/09/10"), 
    ("C", "2017/09/15"), 
    ("D", "2017/10/17"), 
    ("E", "2017/10/19"), 
    ("F", "2017/09/30"),
    ("G", "2017/10/30"),
    ("H", "2017/11/07"),
    ("I", "2017/11/18"),
    ("J", "2017/11/29")
]
)
df_data2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["id","date"])
```

Now let's create a new column with `datetime` corresponding to the date strings.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt_parse = udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%Y/%m/%d"), DateType())
df_data2 = df_data2.withColumn('datetime', dt_parse(df_data2.date))
```

And finally

```
interval = 60 * 60 * 24 * 42    # 6 weeks in seconds
gdf = df_data2.withColumn(
    '6week_interval',
    from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(df_data2.datetime)/interval) * interval + 
                  ((unix_timestamp(lit('2017/09/01'),'yyy/MM/dd')/interval)%1)*interval)
).groupBy('6week_interval').agg(count('*').alias('counts'))
```

I added the `((unix_timestamp(lit('2017/09/01'),'yyy/MM/dd')/interval)%1)*interval` so that the consecutive 6-week intervals start on the first calendar day of the considered period (2017/09/01 in this case).