# Calculate distinct ID for a specified time period

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | area_id | dob | dod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | A | 2000/09/10 | Null |
| id2 | A | 2001/09/28 | 2010/01/02 |
| id3 | B | 2017/09/30 | Null |
| id4 | B | 2019/10/01 | 2020/12/10 |
| id5 | C | 2005/10/08 | 2010/07/13 |

where `dob` is the date of birth and `dod` is the date of death.

I'd like to calculate a distinct number of `IDs` per `area_id` for a specified time period where a time period could be:

- a year (e.g. 2010, 2020, ...)
- a year-month (2010-01, 2020-12, ...)
- ...

This is different from [calculating moving averages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446431/count-id-for-date-range-in-pyspark) or [aggregating by intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129733/group-by-a-pyspark-dataframe-by-time-interval?noredirect=1&lq=1), so I'll appreciate any ideas for more appropriate approaches.

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when `dod` is `null`?

Comment: Respectfully perhaps you might consider removing the requiremnt for (month, quarter) if they aren't tied to a year as it doesn't really hold meaning.

Comment: @snithish - They're `null` they're alive.(no date of death.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. replace nulls with today --> stick in temporary table
2. use where clause with BETWEEN  *use expr function so you can use columns. `expr(" [the date in question] BETWEEN dob and dod ")`
3. group by area_id, ID

Comment: thanks, this is the approach I ended up using

Answer (score 0):

Given that your column schema is as follows.

```
types.StructField('ID', types.StringType())
types.StructField('area_id', types.StringType())
types.StructField('dob', types.DateType())
types.StructField('dod', types.DateType())
```

You can use pyspark.sql functions like the following.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

#by month
df.groupBy(df["area_id"], functions.month(df["dob"])).count()

#by quarter
df.groupBy(df["area_id"], functions.quarter(df["dob"])).count()

#by year
df.groupBy(df["area_id"], functions.year(df["dob"])).count()

#by year and month
df.groupBy(df["area_id"], functions.year(df["dob"]), functions.quarter(df["dob"])).count()
```

Comment: thanks for taking time to work on this, but your solution would give me the number of IDs born on a given month, year, etc. so it wouldn't answer my original question

Comment: Are you looking to enter a timestamp - timestamp and then aggregate based on that window? If you could provide a sample output that would help!

Answer (score 0):

First you want to find the records that match an arbitrary time period and then apply `collect_set` after grouping on `area_id` for matching rows.

I use an extensible lambda based system that can be extended to arbitrary time period notation. In my example, I cover the notations used as examples in your question. I break down `year-month` into a condition with both `year` and `month` specified.

> I have modified the input to include cases to better illustrate the idea

### `Step 1`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("id1", "A", "2000/09/10", "2021/11/10"),
        ("id2", "A", "2001/09/28", "2020/10/02",),
        ("id3", "B", "2017/09/30", None),
        ("id4", "B", "2017/10/01", "2020/12/10",),
        ("id5", "C", "2005/10/08", "2010/07/13",), ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("ID", "area_id", "dob", "dod",))\
          .withColumn("dob", F.to_date("dob", "yyyy/MM/dd"))\
          .withColumn("dod", F.to_date("dod", "yyyy/MM/dd"))

df.show()
#+---+-------+----------+----------+
#| ID|area_id|       dob|       dod|
#+---+-------+----------+----------+
#|id1|      A|2000-09-10|2021-11-10|
#|id2|      A|2001-09-28|2020-10-02|
#|id3|      B|2017-09-30|      null|
#|id4|      B|2017-10-01|2020-12-10|
#|id5|      C|2005-10-08|2010-07-13|
#+---+-------+----------+----------+

# Map of supported extractors
extractor_map = {"quarter": F.quarter, "month": F.month, "year": F.year}

# specify conditions using extractors defined
# Find rows such that the 2019-10 lies between `dob` and `dod` 
conditions = {"month": 10, "year": 2019}


# Iterate throught the conditions and in each iterations 
# update the conditional expression to include the result of the 
# condition evaluation after extracting value using the appropriate extractor

# The extractor are not `null` safe and will evaluate to `null`
# depending on how you want to tackle null, you can modify the condition
conditional_expression = F.lit(True)

for term, condition in conditions.items():
    extractor = extractor_map[term]
    conditional_expression = (conditional_expression) & (F.lit(condition).between(extractor("dob"), extractor("dod")))
    
condition_example = df.withColumn("include", conditional_expression)

condition_example.show()

#+---+-------+----------+----------+-------+
#| ID|area_id|       dob|       dod|include|
#+---+-------+----------+----------+-------+
#|id1|      A|2000-09-10|2021-11-10|   true|
#|id2|      A|2001-09-28|2020-10-02|   true|
#|id3|      B|2017-09-30|      null|   null|
#|id4|      B|2017-10-01|2020-12-10|   true|
#|id5|      C|2005-10-08|2010-07-13|  false|
#+---+-------+----------+----------+-------+
```

### `Step 2`

```py
# Filter rows that match the condition
df_to_group = condition_example.filter(F.col("include") == True)

# Grouping on `area_id` and collecting distinct `ID`
df_to_group.groupBy("area_id").agg(F.collect_set("ID")).show()
```

#### Output

```
+-------+---------------+
|area_id|collect_set(ID)|
+-------+---------------+
|      B|          [id4]|
|      A|     [id2, id1]|
+-------+---------------+
```